# App was not working in some mobile devices

Tags: android, android-video-player, video-recording

I developed an application. My application includes video recording and playing.

I have to play video what I have recorded from mobile. This is working in most of devices`(Samsung galaxy ace,Motorola Droid x, etc.,)` and not working in some of devices`(Droid x2,Nexus,etc.,)`.

I used below code for video playing

```
String temp_path=Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM)+"/MySaveCellData/dbz_115.3gp";
    //Toast.makeText(this,getSaveCellPath(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    if(temp_path!=null) {
            //int width = myView.getMeasuredWidth();
          //  int height = myView.getMeasuredHeight();
            //we add 10 pixels to the current size of the video view every time you touch     
            //the media controller.
        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
        int width = display.getWidth();
        int height = display.getHeight();
        MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
        mediaController.setAnchorView(myView);
        myView.setMediaController(mediaController);
       
        myView.setKeepScreenOn(true);

        //myView.setVideoAspect(width,height);
        //myView.setVideo
        myView.setVideoPath(temp_path);
        myView.start();
        myView.requestFocus();
    }
    else 
        Toast.makeText(this,"Video Path Not Found, or is set to null",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();        
}
```

What is the problem and solution?

Comment: the video was not playing in some of mobiles

Comment: Was there any stacktrace or other unusual output in `logcat` on these devices?

Comment: in your code u had use Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory that is work not working in lower lavel api. in which device application not run? try to log error and edit your question. instant of that method use Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() its work on 2.1 and +.

Comment: @milind the video playing is not working in 2.2 and +

Comment: @PhilippReichart i tested it in droid x2 yesterday now i don't have that mobile.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because there isn't a fault report here (e.g. an error message).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not in video playing. The problem in video recording. When I record the video the hardware of device is not supporting to my code. So I changed the code of video recorder. It is working well in all devices.